# JQuery draggable event not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The following code works fine in any browser, except Internet Explorer 9;

```
    $(".dragbox").draggable({
        handle: ".header",
        grid: [1, 1],
        containment: 'parent',
        reflow: true,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //do not update the widgets pos/size not even by accident when we are in forced rearrange mode
            if (jQuery('#widget_content').hasClass('floating-dashboard-widgets'))
                return false;
            var id = ui.helper.context.id.split('_')[1];
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/user/dbview/update/id/'; ?>" + id,
                data: {data: {left: ui.position.left, top: ui.position.top, parent_width: get_parent_width(), parent_height: get_parent_height()}},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.status == 'true') {
                    }
                },
                dataType: 'json',
            });
        }
    });
```

I have multiple draggable element and I can't change them from `div` tags to `a` tags, as requested by IE9;

and as i have read, I must use also something like this:

```
$('#demo1_box')
        .bind('drag',function( event ){
                $( this ).css({
                        top: event.offsetY,
                        left: event.offsetX
                        });
                });
```

but this bind method does not have any containment element;

What solutions do I have in this case?

Comment: `IE8` or `IE9`? Title and body are different.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: yes i did; check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to develop a app using [jslate](http://jslate.com/pages/home);

I rechecked the html code that i was using for the draggable elements, and i noticed that a `div` element was missing from my code;

After I completed the html code, foollowing the jslate pattern, it worked like magic;